# Redis / RedisSearch slows down after some time

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis, redisjson, redis-stack-server, redis-search

I have a Redis Stack running inside a podman container, that slows down for specific commands after just a couple of hours of uptime.
*(Redis v6.2.13, RediSearch v. 2.6.12, RedisJSON v. 2.4.7)*

For example, `FT.SEARCH idx LIMIT 0 0`  that counts entries on a specific index runs slower and slower over time.

I have a .NET service that inserts data (150k keys, stored as JSON) every ~10min, and each key expires at a different time (TTL is different for each index).

The main consumer is a .net API, serving ~70 clients that retrieves data from Redis every ~15sec.
I'm monitoring SLOWLOG and commands duration increase from ~10ms when the container start to ~300ms after 24h. This happens for just a couple of commands (especially `FT.SEARCH idx LIMIT 0 0` )

Both .net services use [Redis.OM](https://redis.io/docs/clients/om-clients/stack-dotnet/).
Everything goes back to normal when I'm restarting the container.
What could some possible causes be?
Thanks in advance.

I deactivated AOF and let only backups run every 1min or so.
Nothing happens if I restart the sites in IIS (or recycle pools or anything).
I ve turned on memory defragmetion but again nothing happens.

Comment: Are you using Redis Stack?

Comment: @GuyRoyse yes. This is the image version : redis/redis-stack:6.2.6-v9

Comment: What does your Schema look like?

Comment: Problem aside, why not using FT.INFO to get the number of documents in the index?

Comment: @GuyRoyse , what do you mean by Schema?

Comment: @A.Guy , I just went along with out of the box methods provided by Redis.OM. As of now I also suspect I have some kind of memory leak. 
While the old variant (getting data from db and storing it in a memcache) of the app uses about 400mb of memory, the new version (using only redis) goes up to 11gb of memory. 
After using dotMemory (from jetBrains) I can see that the most of memory is used by objects from Redis.OM (especially JObjects, when de/serializing data).
I ll check the memory leak and I hope I'll come back with a solution

Comment: Each instance of the RedisCollection holds all the documents you've enumerated to track them for updates. If you are not updating your documents from the collection (which it sounds like you probably aren't) you can disable this feature by setting `saveState` to false in the constructor/factory method of the RedisCollection. Make sure you aren't holding onto a strong reference to the RedisCollection after they go out of scope (this will prevent GC), also if your data are quite large, it's possible that it's stuck in the Large Object Heap awaiting collection.

Comment: @slorello, I did change my code so every constructor has `saveState` false. The memory issue is solved, but redis still slows done. I'm gonna change the approach and I'll write here the results

Comment: Is it possible that your memory is maxing out and it's switching over to swap? That could potentially slow things down. Maybe try disabling swap? https://docs.redis.com/latest/rs/installing-upgrading/configuring/linux-swap/

Comment: @slorello,  as I can see in my VM, swapping is enabled, but not a single byte is used. 

[after running top](https://imgtr.ee/image/Qmbcu)

But now I can also see that redis uses a lot of cpu time (TIME+). Weird, because the container was up for only 7 hours. I'm thinking that maybe I have too many keys expiring at once. But I still don't have an explanation to why it slows down over time. After 7 hours, in slow log the median value is somewhere around 100ms. After the container is restarted, everything goes back to normal

Comment: Do you have more than one CPU on there? .75 load isn’t terribly concerning if you are running on multi-core but if it’s a single core it could be a bunch of background processes that redis is doing that’s slowing it down?

Comment: Yep, there are more CPUs. I've ran today `LATENCY DOCTOR` and `MEMORY DOCTOR`. 
I've activated `activedefrag` and still runs the same. I'll try setting transparent huge pages to never and see how that goes.
https://imgtr.ee/image/L0Dbv